(Dis)proving $\cos(A+B) \leq \cos B +\cos A$ in $\triangle ABC$
Prove or disprove that in a triangle $ABC$,
$$\cos(A+B) \leq \cos B +\cos A$$
what I tried,
$$ \implies \cos A \cos B - \sin A  \sin B < \cos B + \cos A $$
$$ \implies (1- \cos B)(1-\cos A) < \sin A \sin B +1 $$
after this I don't know how to proceed $\ldots$
This problem campe up to me while I was solving a problem from vietnam Maths Olympiad 1970
origin problem- Prove that in triangle  $$ ABC, \sin \frac{A}{2} \sin \frac{B}{2} \sin \frac{C}{2} < \frac{1}{4} $$
I thought to askt that Inequality beacuse it satisfied the initial values but I was not able to proceed any fruther in proving it

Welcome to Math.SE! ... The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Cosine is decreasing on the interval $[0, \pi]$ so $\cos(A+B) \le \cos A$

@Vasili yah but what about cos $B$ in RHS ? I've tried placing in some values at it is satisfying

Also, $\cos (A+B) \le \cos B$ so...

@Vasili sorry sir I'm not able to to get what you are trying to say, the two inequalities you wrote are true but still if we add those two we would get 2 times LHS I therefore request you to please provide a more clear explanation thanks!

@AlokRajSingh You should tell us which way you wanted to prove.

@BobDobbs the trigonometry way ofcourse

So, your attempt to solve this question is Vasili's way.  True? Did you consider geometric formulas? Or derivatives? @AlokRajSingh

@BobDobbs no I actually used trigonometric identities to manippulate this actually this thing came as sub problem whie solving another trigonometric Inequality problem in triangle

$$\cos (A+B)\leq\cos A +\cos B$$
$$\iff\cos (\pi-C)\leq\cos A +\cos B$$
$$\iff-\cos C\leq\cos A +\cos B$$
$$\iff0\leq\cos A +\cos B+\cos C$$
$$\iff0\leq 1+4\sin\frac A2\sin\frac B2\sin\frac C2$$
due to the formula
$$\cos A+\cos B+\cos C=1+4\sin\frac A2\sin\frac B2\sin\frac C2$$
in a triangle $\triangle ABC.$
Now, each half angle is less than $90^\circ$ so in fact
$$1< 1+4\sin\frac A2\sin\frac B2\sin\frac C2$$
and therefore
$$\cos(A+B)<\cos(A+B)+1<\cos A+\cos B$$
New Edit: You may proceed your way
$$ (1- \cos B)(1-\cos A) < \sin A \sin B +1 $$
$$ \iff4\sin^2\tfrac A2\sin^2\tfrac B2 < \sin A \sin B +1 $$
So, it is enough to show that
$$4\sin^2\tfrac A2\sin^2\tfrac B2<1$$
We know that $A+B<\pi$ so $\frac B2<\frac\pi2-                            \frac A2$ and $\sin\tfrac B2<\sin(\tfrac\pi2-\tfrac A2)=\cos\tfrac A2.$
Hence,
$$4\sin^2\tfrac A2\sin^2\tfrac B2<4\sin^2\tfrac A2\cos^2\tfrac A2=\sin^2A\leq1$$

+1 but does equality holds? if yes then at which angle?

It seems that equality never holds. $\cos(A+B)<\cos A+\cos B$ always.

Cosine is decreasing on the interval $[0,π]$ so $\cos(A+B)≤ \cos A, \cos(A+B)≤ \cos B \implies 2\cos(A+B) \le \cos A +\cos B$
if $\cos(A+B) \ge 0$ we have  $\cos(A+B) \le 2\cos(A+B)$
if $\cos(A+B) < 0$ and $\cos A \ge 0, \cos B \ge 0$ the inequality is obvious
if $\cos(A+B) < 0$ and $\cos A <0, \cos B \ge 0$ the inequality is obvious: $\cos(A+B)≤ \cos A \le \cos A + \cos B$
Both  $\cos A, \cos B$ cannot be negative in a triangle.

does equality hold? if yes then when?

@AlokRajSingh: equality never holds as cosine is strictly decreasing and $A \ne 0, B \ne 0$
